# get_product is now not a usable function?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce 2.3.11 and working in PhpStorm8.
I see here in PhpStorm8 that `get_product()` is crossed out..[image: get_product() is crossed out]

What is the new way to get products then? if I want to follow there standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create the object of WC_Product class

```
$product = new WC_Product($post->ID);
```

Comment: you can also use the `$factory= new WC_Product_Factory();
    $product = factory->get_product($productId);`

Answer (score 0):

If Iam right the function was replaced with wc_get_product.

Check out http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product.html